# How to keep higher level headings visible in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, is there a way to keep higher level headings (superheadings, ancestors) visible as you move around the buffer?

I have a structure with lots of headings at the same level and I'd like to keep the higher level headings which contain them, from scrolling off the top of the window as I move point down the list.

Maybe even a horizontal split, with point in the lower window, and point's 'lineage' of headings in the window above.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `which-function-mode` will display the name of the "function" in the mode line.  For `org-mode` this is the level 1 headline.  If you want the full lineage you can add a function to `which-func-functions` to change how `which-function` determines the function name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such facility in org-mode.

For a solution like that of @erikstokes which would display the outline path in the modeline, I would suggest a less general but (imo) more convenient method: use *org-display-outline-path*. See my answer to this question: [Is there some kind of narrow-to-context in org-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667497/is-there-some-kind-of-narrow-to-context-in-org-mode/38960984#38960984) for more details.