# Is there some kind of narrow-to-context in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Org's `narrow-to-subtree` is wonderful, but sometimes I also want to see the chain of parent nodes, without all the uncle nodes.

For example, given this tree:

```
* a
** a.a     <- extraneous great uncle
** a.b
*** a.b.a  <- extraneous uncle
*** a.b.b  <- want to see context for this
**** a.b.b.a
**** a.b.b.b
```

I want to narrow my view to see this:

```
* a
** a.b
*** a.b.b  <- want to see context for this
**** a.b.b.a
**** a.b.b.b
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Grrr a down vote with no comment. I wish people would lose reputation for doing that. Anyway, I think this is a perfectly valid question, I could definitely see a use case for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such narrowing facility - but the function *org-display-outline-path* will display "a/a.b" for the heading in question, i.e. the outline path of headings above your current heading. You can add the function to the modeline indicator if you want it to be permanently visible - or perhaps use the (normally absent) header line which has more space to grow. Try with this file:

```
* foo

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq header-line-format '(:eval (org-display-outline-path)))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (:eval (org-display-outline-path))


** bar

*** baz
```

Evaluate the code block to set the header-line-format-variable and then see what the header line says when the cursor is on the "** bar" header or the "*** baz" header.

Comment: Huh. Not exactly what I had in mind, but that's great. I didn't even know about the header line thing. Thank you!